# Time dependent Classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, survival-analysis

I am trying to solve a decision making problem. In it, information evolves and increases with time for each event observed, and the history of the event may be useful.

The problem is as follows: in an electric network at time $t_0$ there is signal that automatically triggers the possible need of a technical intervention in a network to correct the problem. The system at $t_0$ has a large set of general indicators describing the state of the network based on which I'd like to determine whether to proceed with an intervention at $t_{0}$.

It's possible to carry specific measurements at the point where the problem was detected (this takes some time $\Delta t$). At this stage we can again ask whether the intervention is necessary or not? We can iterate this procedure a few times. Then, my question is, which is the machine learning method best suited for this classification problem? Can it be formulated as a Survival problem?

Comment: Are you saying that at all times `ti` you have a set of features `xi`, and then if you perform the specific measurements, you'll have `xi` plus some new features, `x2i`?  If the dimensionality changes if you perform these measurements, you'll need to formulate the problem carefully.

Comment: This looks like multi armed bandit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem to me. At different time moments you would like to make a max reward decision given some context, policy. It is implemented in Vowpal Wabbit which scales very well with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the problem, you can just choose whatever classification algorithm you like to classify the need of intervention at  $t_{0}$.

The general rule for choosing a classifier for this is to start simple--e.g., by using nearest neighbor and iterate to more powerful classifiers until you get enough accuracy.

If additional measurements at $t_{0}$ can be made a classifier can be used to determine the necessity of intervention without this additional data, then based on the probability output of this classifier and a threshold the additional measurements can be triggered. Based on this measurements another probability can be output which hopefully uses more informative features.

If you care about $\Delta t$, you should think about wether there is a real time dependency. Does the need of intervention depend upon the **series** of classifications? Is the order of determining interventions as necessary important for you?

In my opinion, you do not have to care about ordering for this application.
Rather, I would suggest pooling classifications for one instance according to the most frequent label or something like that.

Comment: Can you provide some references for your "general rule for choosing a classifier" statement? I agree that parsimony should be a guiding principle in choosing an ML approach, but I disagree that that means starting with nearest neighbors. For example, linear SVM has a single parameter to optimize ($c$), whereas knn has two (choice of $k$ and the distance metric to use).

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of simplicity of the method. Everyone understands NN and is able to implement it if necessary. Linear SVM requires more thought. Additionally NN without the k and by just using euclidean distance has no parameters at all.